# What's the proper way to pass dependencies between components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Imagine that Component A creates a list of items that Component B needs to display. What's the proper way to pass data from Component A to Component B from their parent?

For example, let's say that Component A's constructor creates a list of items and has a function `_getListItems()` that returns that list. I'm hoping the parent can then pass that list on to other components via props.

My naive (non-working) implementation has their parent attempting to render the components like this:

```
render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Data Test</h1>        
        <ComponentA ref='compa'/>
        <ComponentB items={this.refs.compa._getListItems()}/>
      </div>
    );
}
```

....although the code above doesn't work, I hope it illustrates what I'm trying to do.

ps. nOOb to react and javascript, so forgive me if the answer to my question's obvious...

Comment: Oh, just noticed it's not a parent / child.   In that case I often pass state between object using http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Comment: Please "extend answers" in answers, not questions--you can include a separate answer or suggest an edit to the existing answer.

Comment: @DaveNewton - done - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide your components into two separate categories.

- Presentational Component that has responsibility to display a thing. This component should not have state (except for UI state).
- Container Component that knows the data.

https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.skmxo7vt4

So, in your case the data should created by parent of `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` and pass the data to both `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` via props.

Example:

```
render(){
    let items = this._getListItems();
    return (
        <div>
            <ComponentA items={items} />
            <ComponentB items={items} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

#### Edit

Rewrite OP's approach in the comment:

```
class MyContainer extends React.Component { 
    constructor(props) { 
        super(props);
        this.state = { stuff: [1,2,3] }; 
    } 

    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div>
                <ComponentA items={this.state.stuff} /> 
                <ComponentB items={this.state.stuff} /> 
            </div> 
        ); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm new to React, but unless items is read-only, wouldn't items want to be on the state object, so that when changes with setState are fired the UI will update?.

Comment: @Keith It depends on what `_getListItems` do. I often write such function to encapsulate access to state.

Comment: Doh! Seems obvious now - I just need to reorganise! Something like:

```
class MyContainer extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

      
    this.state = {
        stuff: [1,2,3]
    }  
  }

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <ComponentA items={this.state.stuff} />
            <ComponentB items={this.state.stuff} />
        </div>
    );
}

Comment: Last comment went wrong :(

Doh! Seems obvious now - I just need to reorganise! Something like: 

```
class MyContainer extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) { 
super(props) 
this.state = { stuff: [1,2,3] } } render(){ return ( <div> <ComponentA items={this.state.stuff} /> <ComponentB items={this.state.stuff} /> </div> ); }

Comment: @DamienLeroux  What's not the point?, anyone reading that code might imply that such function might mutate state,. So pointing it out surely wasn't a bad thing.  Anyway Niyoko depends part, of course clears things up nicely.

Comment: Arghhh!:

Doh! Seems obvious now - I just need to reorganise! 

Something like: 

``` 
class MyContainer extends React.Component { 
 constructor(props) { 
  super(props) 
  this.state = { 
   stuff: [1,2,3] 
  } 
 } 

 render(){ 
  return ( 
   <div> 
    <ComponentA items={this.state.stuff} /> 
    <ComponentB items={this.state.stuff} /> 
   </div> 
  ); 
 }
}
```

Right?

Comment: @glowkeeper  Just for reference, your able to delete / edit comments.

Comment: @Keith how (edit/delete comments)? I don't seem to have that option available :(

Comment: It's a mouse over option, move you mouse to the end of comment, and an (x) should appear.  You also get 'edit' if it's within a certain time.  Or maybe it's your rep, but didn't think that was linked to rep..

Comment: I don't seem to get that mouseover :(

Anyway, no matter - @Niyoko Yuliawan understood my garbled comment(s) and edited his answer accordingly :) And it works (of course)! I really like it when the answer's a simple matter of adjusting the thought process and reorgainising accordingly. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Following the accepted answer above, I've just had a (related) EUREKA moment, so I'm going to expand on the answer; when the parent uses its own state to pass props to its children, whenever the parent's state changes, its render() function is called, thus updating the children with the updated state. So you can do stuff like this:

```
class MyContainer extends React.Component { 
    constructor(props) { 
        super(props);

        let sltd = this.props.selected
        this.state = { 
          stuff: [1,2,3], 
          selected: sltd
        }; 
    } 

    _handleAStuff(value) {
        this.setState(selected: value)
        //do other stuff with selected...
    }

    _handleBStuff(value) {
        this.setState(selected: value)
        //do other stuff with selected...
    }

    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div>
                <ComponentA items={this.state.stuff} selected={this.state.selected} parentFunc={this._handleAStuff.bind(this)} /> 
                <ComponentB items={this.state.stuff} selected={this.state.selected} parentFunc={this._handleBStuff.bind(this)} /> 
            </div> 
        ); 
    } 
}

MyContainer.defaultProps = {
  selected: 0
}

class ComponentA extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  _handleSelect(value) {
    this.props.parentFunc(value.label)
  }

render() {

    const itm = this.props.items.map(function(values) {
      return { value: values, label: values}
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          options={itm}
          value={this.props.selected}
          onChange={this._handleSelect.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ComponentB...
```

The callback pattern above means that ComponentA and ComponentB do not need to maintain state, they simply 'render stuff', which is also pretty cool. I'm beginning to see the power of REACT...